# Failed to add object to RedissonSet<V>

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I am using redis 6.0.5 and redisson client 3.14.9

My service on prod fails to add object to RedissonSet.
my code looks like this:

```
redissonClient.getSet(setName).add(newValue)
```

The add API returns false sometime, meaning failed to add object.
I don't see any logs of error, and don't know what could be the reason of failures.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/7.-distributed-collections#73-set) link, it looks like some versions of `RedissonSet` object do not support set operations like ultra-fast read/write etc.

Can you check which `RedissonSet` you are using & if possible see if you can upgrade it to `Redisson PRO` version which has most of set operations support.

Comment: do you mean what Radisson client? I am using 3.14.0. does it make sense that sometimes it works and sometimes not?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: do you know if there is an option to get more data from redisson client, logs?

Comment: I am currently not sure on which platform you are executing this application, as its not shared, but if you use any usual `spring` / `spring-boot` kind of platform, then enabling third party logs are pretty simple by just giving root package name of third party library (here raddisonclient ) in your property file.

Comment: then use `logging.level.org.redisson.*` = `INFO`  & see what if it shows anything informative

Comment: upgrade and keep getting false sometimes when adding, do you have recommendation how to investigate, redisson hide the root cause

Comment: @user1116404, when you say it sometimes false, do you saw any improvement as compared to previous observation or you are still getting same  number of errors.

Regarding root cause, as i mentioned you have to enable logger as mentioned above in comments & see whats going on..  for thorough debugging, I would recommend to enable `logging.level.root` = `INFO` so that if there is any raddison dependancy package which is hiding errors, that too will also gets printed.

Comment: @user1116404, hi there, do you still get false sometimes when adding? or did you change the logger level of redisson and see some error messages? I am doing a survey on redisson/Redis so I'm Interested in your situation.